# Projectivity of $\mathbb Q$ over $\mathbb Q\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Q$

Tags: commutative-algebra, projective-module

Consider $\mathbb Q\otimes \mathbb Q$, where $\mathbb Q$ is considered as $\mathbb Z$-algebra and consider $\mathbb Q$ as a right $\mathbb Q\otimes\mathbb Q$ module. Then is it true that $\mathbb Q$ is projective $\mathbb Q\otimes\mathbb Q$-module?

Answer (score 7):

Since $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{Q}$ is a field, every module over it is projective.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the module structure is induced by the ring map $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$, $a \otimes b \mapsto ab$. But this is an isomorphism, so that the module is free of rank $1$. More generally, if $A \to B$ is an epimorphism in the category of commutative rings, then $B \otimes_A B \to B$ is an isomorphism, so that $B$ is free of rank $1$ over $B \otimes_A B$.

Comment: So the argument has nothing to do with linear algebra, we don't need the existence of bases in general, since here simply $\{1\}$ is one.

Comment: $@$Martin: I agree with this answer.  Let me say though that I also felt there was some ambiguity in the intended module structure, so I gave an answer that avoids that issue!

Comment: Hehe, that's clever. On the other hand, all module structures are isomorphic in this case.